# The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 12.0

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode11, ios14, xcode12

I am working on Xcode 12. And I created a new project on Xcode 12. I compile & run it successfully. when I run this project on Xcode 11.3 then It throws an error like: The document “Main.storyboard” requires at least Xcode 12.0 .

So, help me to fix this problem. I want to run this project in a lower version of Xcode 12.

Comment: Select the storyboard and change its version under File Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Since the project is created in Xcode 12. The minimum required Xcode version is Xcode 12. If you want to compile with Xcode 11.3, **recreate the main.storyboard using Xcode 11.3**

Edit:
As pointed out my matt in a comment alternative way is to open main.storyboard as source code and update toolversion value same as Xcode 11.3. (try sample storyboard to find toolversion for Xcode 11.3)

[image]

Comment: Nope.  You can change the storyboard version.

Comment: yes, toolsVersion in storyboard can be changed by opening storyboard as source code. But need to find Xcode 11 toolVersion, to update the correct value for Xcode 11.